# Lost data upgrading roms, but data is still there when viewed with Clockwork and Clockwork alone. Can I recover it?

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, clockworkmod-recovery, data-recovery

I lost my data upgrading to M1 CM10.1 through CMUpdate, but I still see it when I go into clockwork recovery mod. I tried accessing it through adb and adb shell but I cannot find it. Furthermore my Galaxy Nexus is reporting that it's full.

I have tried this method: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1994705
However, it does not recover all my data and if it does it's often renamed and/or corrupted (i.e. images merged together, mp3s losing metadata, and so on)

Is there a way to access it using CWM and copy it to my PC? What commands is CWM using to access that otherwise inaccessible data that I could run from adb?

I tried tweeting the CWM guy but he never got back to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were going from CM10 to CM10.1 — that is, moving from Android 4.1 to 4.2 — your data "loss" is probably because the path to your emulated SD card has changed due to the new multiuser support.  Previously, the SD card was `/data/media`, but now it's a *subdirectory* such as `/data/media/0`, with additional subdirectories (such as `/data/media/1`) for additional user accounts.  The files should've been moved to the new location automatically when you first booted CM10.1, but maybe that didn't happen.

Using a root file manager or shell, create a `/data/media/0` directory if it doesn't exist already, and then move all the *other* files from `/data/media` into the `0` subdirectory, and it should become visible within Android again.

---

If you use ClockworkMod for backups, you may find that it can no longer find your backups directory, because it's still looking for `/data/media/clockworkmod`, not `/data/media/0/clockworkmod`.  You can fix that by creating a symlink in the old location.  From a root shell, run these two commands:

```
cd /data/media
ln -s 0/clockworkmod clockworkmod
```

Comment: I selected this one as answer because it is THE solution, though thanks to Koush i was able to find the data as well.

Comment: you are a wonderful human being

Answer (score 2):

Use `adb shell` and look in `/data/media`.

Should be there.

Comment: Welcome @koush to ASE! The hallowed creator of CWM!!!! As your first time here.... +1... :D

Comment: Thank you so much, after a bit of fiddling with remounting I was able to get all the stuff I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

[Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) offers this when you have the [Pro key](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro).

To get a copy from the cwm folder you can use `adb pull`.

Comment: I can't because it it's inaccessible on adb shell, using the pc or cyanogen file manager so there's absolutely no way I could point to the folder. It's only under clockwork that I am able to see it.

Comment: Also not sure how Titanium would help me, I only need to recover my media. I don't care about the apps.